Fluid simulation - Why does unchecking Use Flow not stop emitting fluid?
I have created a fluid simulation, and after I baked it I wanted to animate when fluid is coming out and when there is not. So I unchecked Use Flow and added keyframes when I dont want fluid to be pouring out. However, it doesn't work, the fluid just keeps on flowing.
When I 'Free All' in order to change some of the settings I also don't have any flow at all. Maybe that's the issue?
Here is the file: 

in the shared file, the Use Flow option is deactivated, if you choose Cache > Type > Replay in order to refresh the cache, it seems to work

Ah yes. So when you want to work on it, you change the Type to Replay and then change the Cache type back to All when you want to bake it again. Is that always the case?

Replay allows you to preview the simulation, once it is good, choose All and Bake All

Okay, clear, thanks!

No, you don't have to switch it to Replay. When you baked the simulation before, you can simply free the cache to delete it and bake again.

Enable the Use Flow option of the inflow object. If you click on Free All it won't recalculate the simulation so you won't see anything, you either need to go into the fluid panel of the domain > Cache > Type > and select Replay to preview the simulation or simply click on Bake All to recalculate the simulation for good.
